# How can I change the size and style of a letter and fill the background of a cell if it contains specific letters?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that cell input could be `X`, `C`, `G` or `T`.

- If the cell has an input `X` I would like font size to be 5 or less (specify) and fill the cell with a style
- If the cell has an input `C`, `G` or `T` then font should be bold, size 11,  font color red or/and cell filled yellow

I have no idea how to even start.

Comment: Start with the macro recorder.

Comment: Thanks for answer but do I open a macro and how do I tell in below that if X size 5 and fill is !!!! line else if cell is C or G or T style is BOLD size is 11 and cell fill yellow. I have NO clue and am trying to learn this , maybe if I get this correct I will understand if I have to use again. BTW the cells are in an excel spreadsheet. THANK YOU for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vityata said - start by recording a macro.  Two macros would probably be better - one to add the formatting and one to remove it again.  Just start recording and change your cell format to what you want.
This will give you code similar to this:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

and one to remove the formatting:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("B2").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = False
End Sub
```

Now, you want to take this code, remove the superfluous bits and join it all together.  For this I'd advise further reading on `With...End With` code blocks and `Select Case` statements.
When I say *superfluous* I mean anything that will default to that value anyway.  Things like `.Strikethrough = False` can be removed as it does that anyway.

We end up with code like this placed inside a normal code module:

```
Public Sub FormatCell(Target As Range)

    With Target
        Select Case .Value
            Case "C", "G", "T"
                With .Font
                    .Bold = True
                    .Size = 11
                    .Color = -16776961
                End With
                .Interior.Color = 65535
            Case "X"
                'Add code if the cell is X.
            Case Else
                .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End Select
    End With

End Sub
```

I've placed the code in it's own procedure rather than a worksheet event so it can be called from different places.  The code will format the cell in the *case* of it being C, G or T.  If it's X it will do nothing (got to add that bit of code), if it's anything else it will remove the formatting.

You can call the code from a worksheet event like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    FormatCell Target
End Sub
```

`Target` is the cell being changed and you pass this variable to your procedure.  You may want to add code that checks a single cell has been selected or that a specific cell address is changing.

**Note:** Most of what you want can be accomplished with conditional formatting except the font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in Worksheet which you want:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target = Range("B2") Then
      'Do some thing
   End If
End Sub
```